# Como são feitas as API não oficiais?

Tags: api

Gostaria de criar uma API do Xbox em PHP que retornasse as informações do usuário, pois não existe uma oficial. Como que isso pode ser feito? Utilizando um crawler? Vi que existe o CasperJS, utilizei ele e realmente até consegui pegar algumas informações, mas não queria utilizar o NodeJS como backend.

Comment: Estou reabrindo esta pergunta (junto com outros 3 usuários) por entendê-la como um pedido de orientação, e não um pedido de um tutorial completo de como criar a API.

Comment: Exatamente! Não foi um pedido de como fazer, mas sim qual a melhor forma. Existem diversos meios mas qual o mais adequado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A grande maioria das APIs não oficiais funciona bem assim mesmo.

O primeiro mais importante passo é ler com muita atenção os **Termo de Uso**, se algum.

Se não houverem restrições, você começa a delinear o **seu** serviço, verificando o quê a Microsoft oferece como recurso aos jogadores e, com isso, esquematizar suas próprias e bem definidas URIs.

Uma API tem de ser o mais descritiva possível para que só de ler o URI você tenha uma noção do que será retornado.

Depois de preparado você faz o seu serviço funcionar com aquele bê-a-bá básico de hoje em dia (rteamento, MVC...).

Hora de considerar a segurança. Uma API, mesmo pública, requer segurança até mesmo para que você possa controlar o fluxo de dados e impedir que alguém tenha um serviço de maior sucesso às suas custas.

O mais simples dos meios se faz com *tokens* onde o programador consumidor registra o desejo de usar sua API e seu sistema retorna uma chave de autorização a qual o programador envia a cada requisição.

Então você começa a estudar o código-fonte das páginas dos recursos, analisando com algum parser (X)(HT)ML ou regularmente (ER). Com o chamado *parser*, dependendo da linguagem, pode ser mais trabalhoso, mas é o mais ideal já que se o desenvolvedor original (Microsoft) mudar uma aspa dupla para simples sua API pode não funcionar mais.

Dependendo do caso convém até mesmo cachear as requisições, por ID de usuário talvez para diminuir tanto o número de requisições feitas quanto a banda consumida pelos programadores que vierem a usar sua API.

Bons estudos :)

Comment: Nossa muito obrigado pela resposta! Você sabe se existe algum crawler/spider em PHP ou .NET? Eu encontrei o CasperJS (muito bom por sinal) mas não queria usar o NodeJS como backend.

Comment: Bom, isso são outros quinhentos. Além de fugir (e muito >.<) dos meus conhecimentos, diferentemente de um fórum, caracteriza uma nova dúvida e, para isso, um novo tópico.